# Is there a specific symbol for $\mathbb{N}\cup\lbrace 0\rbrace$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, integers, natural-numbers

It is well known that natural numbers start in 1.

However, sometimes people work with a "widened set" of natural numeres plus zero, $\mathbb{N}\cup\lbrace 0\rbrace$. That is, all non-negative integers.

Is there a specific symbol for this set? such as $\mathbb{N}^{*}$, $\mathbb{Z}^+$ or anything similar? Thank you

Comment: It's actually pretty common to take $\mathbb{N}$ to include zero. I'm not sure which convention is more common; if anything, I think it's a bit more common to include zero.

Comment: "*It is well known that natural numbers start in 1*"  No... it is a disagreed upon definition.  *Many* authors have the natural numbers starting from $0$, not $1$.  Starting from $1$ happens to also be done by some other authors, but to say that the natural numbers start from $1$ with no further clarification as though it is a universal fact is just flat wrong.

Comment: It's been many years since I've seen the naturals defined without including $0$.

Comment: As another aside, the plus sign, $+$, does *not* have the meaning you intend.  You mean to have the *union* which is represented by $\cup$, so you should have said $\Bbb N\cup \{0\}$

Comment: A union symbol would be preferable to $+$, like this: $\mathbb N \cup \{ 0 \}$ or $\mathbb Z^+ \cup \{ 0 \}$. I also agree with @DanielHast that many authors use the convention that $\mathbb N$ includes $0$.

Comment: As yet another aside... $\Bbb Z^+$ is a choice of notation for the *strictly positive* integers and as such would not include zero, not the set you are after.  Asterisks are commonly used to denote the nonzero elements of whatever set though admittedly is not often seen with $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb N$.  It is seen more commonly with $\Bbb R^*$ or $\Bbb Q^*$ to mean the nonzero reals or nonzero rationals respectively.

Comment: So true, it's been too long without sleep, I was feeling weird about writing the + symbol but I wasn't coming up with the union symbol, for some reason. Edited

Comment: @JMoravitz I've seen $Z^+$ as non-negative and $Z^{++}$ for strictly possitive, but I don't know if that's a rare choice of someone or something more general

Comment: Shall I delete the question? As I see it's a dupe, altough it didn't show me when I stated the question...

Comment: $\mathbb Z^{\geq 0}$ or $\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$ is reasonably common and, unlike most of the alternatives, is unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{N}_0$ is the most common choice.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen $\mathbb{N}_0$.  But saying $n\ge 0$ is not heavy lifting.